# How to include/exclude API block in RAML output dynamically

Tags: mule, mulesoft, raml

I'm just curious to understand what are the possibilities are excluding/including endpoint(s) in the documentation generated from a RAML.

For example, given

```
#%RAML 1.0
baseUri: https://api.mybanks.com/v1
title: MyBanks-API
version: v1
protocols: [HTTP, HTTPS]
mediaType: application/json

/banks:
  get:
    description: Lists all banks
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          text/plain:
            example: ['b1', 'b2']
/accounts:
  get:
    description: List all accounds
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          text/plain:
            example: ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
```

I want to exclude the `/banks` API from the generated documentation. What are the possible ways to do that ? (preferably without commenting)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way (AFAIK) to dynamically exclude snippets of your API spec--moreover, what would be the semantics of such a feature?  i.e. what is the meaning?  Another consideration, how does it apply when you take the spec and start implementing it?

Now there is a way you can extend an existing API spec with a RAML `extension`. https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#extensions

If you use a RAML `extension` fragment the Spec will be split in two files:

1) The root RAML file:

```
#%RAML 1.0
baseUri: https://api.mybanks.com/v1
title: MyBanks-API
version: v1
protocols: [HTTP, HTTPS]
mediaType: application/json

/accounts:
  get:
    description: List all accounds
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          text/plain:
            example: ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
```

2) The `extension` fragment:

```
#%RAML 1.0 Extension
extends: banks-api.raml

/banks:
  get:
    description: Lists all banks
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          text/plain:
            example: ['b1', 'b2']
```

Now you have two views of your API, (1) the root and (2) the `extension`.   You can provide the root or the `extention` to your users.